# Переключение языков Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог переключать язык сайта. Нужно менять язык темы, не нужен перевод контента. Перепробовал все плагины-не выходит. Тема carspot(лицензия)

Comment: А перевод-то есть? Если в админке вручную переключить, тема отображается на другом языке?

Comment: Уточни - гости должны менять язык на фронте, при этом контент будет тот же? Или же менять язык в админке для авторизованных пользователей?